# I can't disable horizontal scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, mobile

I have a menu off the screen which reveals after clicking on the reveal menu button.But because of that menu there's a horizontal scroll appearing.It’s spoiling the user experience. My website:sadmansyfe.ga.
I have tried everything but nothing is working out.
Scroll doesn’t appear if I shrink the web browser in desktop.It only occurs in mobile.

Comment: Can you please provide your code to create a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: have you used `overflow: hidden;` CSS property in for mobile screens

Comment: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: @ControlAltDel We have to be careful with that because he might have some clipping issues after it. I guess we need to wait for his example to figure out if he will get some problems with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In addition to the Minimal, Reproducible Example, it will be helpful to know what Mobile device or Browsers you are using for testing. Also if you set your Desktop browser to act as a Mobile browser, do you also see this activity?